# Java: Transfer Eclipse Project from One Computer to Another?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse to write my code in Java. I switch back and forth from home computer to work computer on a regular basis. I wanted to be able to sync the work done on one computer to the other computer automatically - how can it be done?

Further, I want to export all the files from my work computer to home computer as I do not have eclipse setup on my home computer yet. I know I can export the files but this will not export the all the Java jars I imported in my project. Basically I want to export everything so once I import it on my home computer I can continue from wherever I left off at work..

Thanks

Comment: Is there a suitable version control sever accessible from both places?

Comment: this may be a very crude way of doing it but you could just copy your workspace from one PC to the other one. :)

Comment: @toskv That's too easy. Copying zipped folders is for noobs. There must be some distributed SCM and lotsa cyptic command lines involved, and maybe some paid remote upstream cloud webservice hoster thing. Yay.

Comment: @Marco13 I agree, anything that takes less than a week to get running behind a corporate firewall is for noobs.

Answer (score 2):

The best bet, would be setting up a version control system like GIT (e.g : using github) and then you will have the chance to easily synch through the remote repository. 
Regarding the libraries used by your project, to keep them organized and automatically managed you can take a look at [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) build tool.

If you don't want to go with the version control system, though it will be the best option, you can try with the [FileSynch](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync) plugin and work through an FTP site or whatever shared location you want ...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to auto sync projects in eclipse, since there is no account/cloud system for projects so you will have to do the job manually. But I can offer you an alternative as long as all the computers are at home (connected to the same router) , there is something in windows called a home group, it enables sharing of documents and devices like printers, faxes, etc. you can make a home group and share the document folder of the user and place the eclipse workspace there then you can just use it whenever you want (your host computer needs to be always online though but you can just copy the folder to the computer and switch workspace via project > switch workspace in eclipse) , then it's the closest you can get to auto sync. I don't know about other OS but I think they should support some equivalents form of a homegroup, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this using the dropbox for a while, Install dropbox app in both computers, then turn on sync :)